# Display javascript nested objects to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, javascript-objects

Here is what the `data` looks like:

```
{
    "1111": {
        [{
            id: "1111",
            name: "name",
            randomvalue: "1",
        },
        {
            id: "1111",
            name: "name2",
            randomvalue: "2",
        }]
    },
    "0101": {
        [{
            id: "0101",
            name: "name3",
            randomvalue: "3"
        },
        {
            id: "0101",
            name: "name4",
            randomvalue: "1"
        }]
    },
    "0001": {
        [{
            id: "0001",
            name: "name5",
            randomvalue: "4"
        }]
    }
}
```

the `randomvalue` always changes when there is new data but the ids and names stay constant.
I want the data to be displayed on html exactly as it is here but when the random values update, the html must also be updated. I am not using any frameworks just nodejs.

For clarity:
for each object a new html `<div>` element will be created.
each `<div>` will have three `<p>` values.
the result will initially look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">1111</p>
    <p class="name">name</p>
    <p class="randomval">1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">1111</p>
    <p class="name">name2</p>
    <p class="randomval">2</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">0101</p>
    <p class="name">name3</p>
    <p class="randomval">3</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">0101</p>
    <p class="name">name4</p>
    <p class="randomval">1</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">0001</p>
    <p class="name">name5</p>
    <p class="randomval">4</p>
</div>
```

if there is a `randomvalue` change in every object it will be:

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">1111</p>
    <p class="name">name</p>
    <p class="randomval"> <new_random_value> </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">1111</p>
    <p class="name">name2</p>
    <p class="randomval"> <new_random_value> </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">0101</p>
    <p class="name">name3</p>
    <p class="randomval"> <new_random_value> </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">0101</p>
    <p class="name">name4</p>
    <p class="randomval"> <new_random_value> </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p class="id">0001</p>
    <p class="name">name5</p>
    <p class="randomval"> <new_random_value> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to post how you are rendering your html, how the values will change, and what you've tried. Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Show what you have tried and where you are stuck. When practical post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this

```js
const toHtml = data => data.map(({id, name, randomvalue}) => {
  return `<div class="container">
    <p class="id">${id}</p>
    <p class="name">${name}</p>
    <p class="randomval"> ${randomvalue} </p>
</div>`

}).join('')


const initialData  = {
    "1111": 
        [{
            id: "1111",
            name: "name",
            randomvalue: "1",
        },
        {
            id: "1111",
            name: "name2",
            randomvalue: "2",
        }]
    ,
    "0101": 
        [{
            id: "0101",
            name: "name3",
            randomvalue: "3"
        },
        {
            id: "0101",
            name: "name4",
            randomvalue: "1"
        }]
    ,
    "0001": 
        [{
            id: "0001",
            name: "name5",
            randomvalue: "4"
        }]
    
}

const toArray = data => Object.values(initialData).flat()
const groupById = data => data.reduce((res, item) =>({...res, [item.id]: [...(res[item.id] || []), item]}), {})

document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = toHtml(toArray(initialData))



setTimeout(() => {
 const newData = toArray(initialData).map(item => ({...item, randomvalue: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)}))
 document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = toHtml(newData)

}, 3000)
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re going to need to write some recursion parsing of your object for a custom display.
If you just need the show the data, you can use `json.stringify(yourData)`